# blur event not working as expected for custom autocomplete feature in angular

Tags: angular, onblur

I have created a custom autocomplete searchbar in my angular app. I tried to call a method on blur event such that the list of search suggestions disappears after the users click outside the list.But this works only after I first click on one of the suggestions in the list and then clicking outside the list.

Below is the code :

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm ">

      <div class=" input-group mb-3 ">
        <input #searchBox [formControl]="queryField" type="text" class="form-control" (focus)="OnFocus(searchBox.value)"
          placeholder="Type any location" aria-label="locationName" aria-describedby="button-addon2" required>

        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-success" type="button" id="button-addon2">

            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>

          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="displayList" tabindex="-1" (blur)="OnBlur()">
        <ul class="list-group typeAhead" *ngIf="locations.length>0">
          <li *ngFor="let location of locations" class="list-group-item">
            {{location.title}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
```

**component ts file**

```
  OnBlur(){
    this.displayList = false;
  }

  OnFocus(value){
    if(value.length>1){
       this.displayList = true;
    }
    else{
      this.displayList = false;
    }
  }
```

I tried focusout event but it gave the same result.

Comment: Blur event is depended on focus, when element not focused can't blur.
You can use blur only on input or textarea or contenteditable.

Comment: But when I use blur within the input element, the list disappears on selecting one of the suggestions and also on clicking outside the searchbar